# How to install latest version of Node using Brew

Tags: macos, homebrew

The latest version of NodeJs right now is 0.4.1

The command `brew install node` right now, installs 0.2.6 - which is not ideal. I would like 0.4.1

I've looked at [this list of commands](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/the-brew-command) for brew and tried `brew install --HEAD node`

But that installs node 0.5-pre.

Why isn't brew installing the right version and how can I force it to get the right one?

At this stage, it looks like it would actually be easier just to download the src and install it manually. But I would like to know what's going on with Brew.

Comment: I am curious. What is the difference between installing via Homebrew and installing from the package downloaded from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org)?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Have you run `brew update` first? If you don't do that, Homebrew can't update its formulas, and if it doesn't update its formulas it doesn't know how to install the latest versions of software.

Comment: Right, I'd tried 'brew update node' but I see now you are right. It didn't occur to me because the doco says that 'brew update' would update the brew software - which would seem to make no difference. But it mentions 'formulea' - which is just a (frankly) stupid word for what is basically it's 'library of software versions'. I can do 'brew info node' to find out what version it's going to install. It's set to 0.4.0 so I ended up installing from src anyway, but this is right. Thank you.

Comment: When it says "update the brew software" it doesn't mean update software that brew has installed - it means update brew itself, as well as its library of Formulae.

Answer (score 382):

Run commands below, in this order:

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew upgrade node
```

Now you have installed updated version of node, and it's probably not linked. If it's not, then just type: `brew link node` or `brew link --overwrite node`

Comment: Keep getting `/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.`

Comment: @SabaAhang, see: Fix permissions on /usr/local for Homebrew ; ; https://gist.github.com/rpavlik/768518

Comment: Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node

Comment: Nice, this fixed an NPM failure ("Buffer.alloc is not a function") because the node keg was unlinked; needed to force link/overwrite old files.

Comment: `brew link --overwrite node` it's really of importance! thanks

Comment: @SabaAhang Just run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

Answer (score 168):

After installation/upgrading node via brew I ran into this issue exactly: the node command worked but not the npm command.

I used these commands to fix it.

```
brew uninstall node
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install node
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
brew link --overwrite node
brew postinstall node
```

I pieced together this solution after trial and error using...

- a github thread: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3125
- this site: http://developpeers.com/blogs/fix-for-homebrew-permission-denied-issues

Comment: `sudo brew postinstall node` will throw an error unless brew is owned by root (not recommended). I don't think it should be needed if you already did `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`. You should be able to just run `brew postinstall node`.

Comment: @SamFen 's right. `sudo` not needed. I first ran the accepted answer before I gave this listing of commands a go.
Afterwards I ran `node -v` and everything seems fine now.

Comment: Use sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/* instead of sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local

Answer (score 28):

Also, try to deactivate the current node version after installing a new node version. It helps me.

```
nvm deactivate
```

This is removed /Users/user_name/.nvm/*/bin from $PATH

And after that node was updated

```
node --version
v10.9.0
```

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes `brew update` fails on me because one package doesn't download properly. So you can just upgrade a specific library like this:

```
brew upgrade node
```

https://gist.github.com/3005832

Answer (score 15):

If you have installed current node via `Homebrew`, just use these commands.

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

Check node version by

`node -v`

Answer (score 15):

1. `node -v` will show you the current version.
2. `npm -v` will show you the current version.
3. `brew link --overwrite --dry-run node` will force the link and overwrite all conflicting files.
4. `brew install node` do a fresh installation.
5. `brew update`
6. `brew upgrade node`
7. `brew link --overwrite node`

   or

   `brew link node`

[Node Upgrade Procedure are below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYurs.png)

Comment: This might be helpful to some -/usr/local/include/node is not writable https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/Error%3A+Could+not+symlink+include%2Fnode%2Fcommon.gypi+%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Finclude%2Fnode+is+not+writable.

Answer (score 13):

I had to do `brew link --overwrite node` after `brew install node` to update from 0.4 to 0.8.18

Comment: Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node

Answer (score 9):

Try to use "n" the Node *extremely simple* package manager.

```
> npm install -g n
```

Once you have "n" installed. You can pull the latest node by doing the following:

```
> n latest
```

I've used it successfully on Ubuntu 16.0x and MacOS 10.12 (Sierra)

Reference: https://github.com/tj/n

Answer (score 6):

Just used this solution with Homebrew 0.9.5 and it seemed like a quick solution to upgrade to the latest stable version of node.

```
brew update
```

This will install the latest version

```
brew install node
```

Unlink your current version of node use, node -v, to find this

```
brew unlink node012
```

This will change to the most up to date version of node.

```
brew link node
```

Note: This solution worked as a result of me getting this error:

> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node

Answer (score 5):

I tried everything here, but apparently, I had used nvm to install node. So I just ran

```
nvm deactivate
```

And then

```
brew install node
node -v
```

Answer (score 4):

I did this on Mac OSX Sierra. I had Node 6.1 installed but Puppetter required Node 6.4. This is what I did:

```
brew upgrade node
brew unlink node
brew link --overwrite node@8
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And then open a new terminal window and run:

```
node -v
v8.11.2
```

The --overwrite is necessary to override conflicting files between node6 and node8

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nodebrew](https://github.com/hokaccha/nodebrew). It can switch node versions too.

Answer (score 2):

if the node is not installed then

```
brew install node
```

If you have an older version of the node installed then remove it and re-install freshly that's the only suitable way.

Make sure to add the path in the environment file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to remove the `brew` dependency, I would recommend [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - I can't really recommend it over any other versioning solution because I haven't needed to try anything else.  Having the ability to switch instantly between versions depending on which project you're working on is pretty valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Just go old skool - https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
From there you can get the current or LTS versions

Answer (score 1):

sudo n latest

OR

brew update

brew upgrade node

Reference:
https://bytearcher.com/articles/ways-to-get-the-latest-node.js-version-on-a-mac/