# "node -v" shows wrong version after "brew upgrade node"

Tags: node.js, version, homebrew

I upgraded my version of Node.js with `brew upgrade node` which installed v5.3.0. But when I get the version of node with `node -v` it shows v0.10.29.

I tried `brew link --overwrite node` but that didn't work.

Brew has node linked to `/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.29` so I went there and noticed that there are other versions of node including the version I want in `/usr/local/Cellar/node/`.

How do I tell brew to link node to `/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.3.0` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to `brew link --override node`

Also see related question [How to install latest version of Node using Brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056115/how-to-install-latest-version-of-node-using-brew/).

Comment: That didn't work, it responded with `Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.29
To relink: brew unlink node && brew link node`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I tried that and it just re-linked it to 0.10.29, I think I will try deleting the other versions and seeing what happens... yep that worked!!

Comment: Given that this answer has gotten more upvotes and seems to be helping the most, I'm going to make it the accepted answer

Comment: "Invalid option: --override"

Comment: Should be `brew link --overwrite node`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the other versions of node that I didn't want in `/usr/local/Cellar/node/` and then ran `:> brew unlink node && brew link node` and it fixed the problem.